# Creating Strings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I originally learned Swift. Now, I am trying to learn Objective-C, but I am having some difficulty. They seem a lot more different than I originally thought. Here, I am simply trying to display "Hello World". This is in the .m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

name = *"World";

NSString word = @"Hello";

self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", word, name];


}
```

In my .h file I have:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

NSString *name;
```

}

Comment: Change `name = *"World";`  to `name = @"World";` and `NSString word = @"Hello";`
 to `NSString *word = @"Hello";`

Comment: There's also shouldn't be a comma in between `"%@ %@"`

Comment: I would recommend to start with `C` language first to learn the basics.

Comment: You haven't asked a specific question here -- please do more than just post code. When you compile this, Xcode gives you a list of errors: what are they, and what do you not understand about what the compiler is telling you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, Objective-C has some extra symbol stuff going on when compared to Swift. I recommend reading or watching some tutorials on the basics. Also, repetition always helps when learning. The code below should work for you. Be sure to pay attention to the details.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

name = @"World";

NSString *word = @"Hello";

self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", word, name];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C variables are declared `VariableType variableName = Value;` for example

```
NSInteger number = 10;
```

If `VariableType` is an **object** like `NSString` you have to add an asterisk and unlike Swift a literal string must start with a leading `@`.

```
NSString *name = @"World";
NSString *word = @"Hello";

self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", word, name];
```

You are encouraged to read Apple's language guide [Working with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1)